# Issues due to sudden load disconnection/connection

Tags: switches, boost, load

I am  working on a circuit (schematic enclosed) which is being powered by a high discharge LiSOCl2 battery. A [TPS61232](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TPS61230) based 5V booster powers two loads: LOAD1 is directly connected to the 5V bus whereas LOAD2 is isolated using a [TPS22917](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps22917.pdf) switch. LOAD2 is a heavy load compared to LOAD1 and could consume current upto 1 A (unlike LOAD1 which has a nominal current consumption of 50 mA). When LOAD2 is switched OFF/ON by TPS22917, could it create some noise over the 5V bus that could interfere with LOAD1 or the booster (even though the switch has adjustable fall time and adjustable turn ON time features)?

[image]

Comment: Please share the values of C1, R1, etc as well.

Comment: @Huisman, C1 and C2 are both 1 uF. I am going to use a cap of ~200 pF for C3 and the value of C4 is ~200 ohm.